# how to obtain Targets of an event

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, delegates

I have an event to fire, named ValueGenerated. The code that generates values and fires ValueGenerated is running in a thread and the method which recieves this event is on a form.control (i.e. a form). As UI thread does not allow another thread to change the UI I wrote the following code on the event generation:

```
if (ValueGenerated.Target is System.windows.form.control)
{
Control targetForm = ValueGenerated.Target as control;
targetForm.Invoke(ValueChanged,new object[]{this,args});
}
```

But I think what happens if the event is registered by more than one methode. For example, by two or three destinations. Why on the event and delegate classes we have just the Target property which returns the instance object of the last method added? Do we always need just the last one?

Comment: Use GetInvocationList to get all the subscribed Delegates. Then you can inspect them all to see what the Targets are.

Comment: Who says you can't update the UI from another thread ?

Comment: The actual backing store for an event is a MulticastDelegate.  Extends Delegate by allowing multiple subscribers.  Hiding a potential threading bug is a very bad idea.  Especially Invoke(), so apt to cause deadlock, you never need it since event handler methods don't have a return value.  And especially events that affect the UI, so often goes wrong when the worker thread keeps running but the user closed the window.  Don't do it.

Comment: to jim:read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649143.aspx#scag-ch06_topic4

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.

As noted in the comments, you can get the full list of invocation targets by calling `GetInvocationList()` on the delegate instance. Then you can invoke each target individually.

But this is *not* the right way to do it. Your event should treat all handlers the same.

If the event is the kind of event that is *always* raised in a background thread, and is *always* handled by a UI object, then it should *always* use an appropriate mechanism to dispatch to the UI thread. See the `BackgroundWorker` class for an example of this sort of design, specifically its `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events.

If either of those conditions are not true, then your event should not attempt to deal with the cross-thread invocation in any way. Subscribers to the event that have thread affinity should be expected to deal with that themselves.

Unfortunately, there's not enough context in your question to provide any more specific advice than that. The only thing that is clear is that you've started down a dead-end road. Turn around, come back, and take the smoother path. :)

Comment: I think this solution is ok. But I want the BackgroundWorker's operation as a component. For example, i want a component that calculates a function like sin(t) every 100 millisecond and fires an event containing the value of the function. This event may be used by a graphic control (like a gauge) to show to the user. I want to have this signal generator as a component likely to be droped on a form. Is it a good idea to extend it from BackgroundWorker?

Comment: For your specific example, there are two problems: 1) long-running operations aren't appropriate for `BackgroundWorker`, because they tie up thread pool threads, and 2) an operation that simply computes a trig function periodically has no inherent relationship to thread-affinitied objects, and so including thread-affinity features in such a component seems unwarranted and over-complicating. That said, in that example, maybe a C# `event` isn't really the best way to surface that behavior anyway; it seems like an `async` method with a loop and a call to `await Task.Delay(100);` would be better.

Comment: No, you didn't get it. I need a component that generates the values, and there are the listeners that register to this component to recieve this event.(Like a clock pulse generator that generates signal for components of a circuit) The value generation is not controlled by others and a value is not obtained in response of a call (eventually async as your proposition)